# Can I just copy and duplicate a WordPress installation?

Tags: multisite

I have a virtual server at Strato with Plesk 11 installed. There I got offered to install WordPress and created a blog. All fine. It has created a "/wordpress" folder on my server's `httpdocs` directory.
Say, I wanted to have a second installation of WordPress on the same server, running a different blog. Can I just go and duplicate the WordPress subdirectory? Is everything that is needed for WordPress inside that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would end up with broken links if you simply copied the files over to a new folder.

What you would need to do to avoid this is install a plugin like WP Migrate DB and enter in the new server path.

You would then need to create another database taking note of the name, username and password which you would need to change in the wp-config.php file of the new installation.

If its a new site without any content or customization, you would be better off to simply install a new version of WorPress in a new folder on your server.

Here's the way to install WordPress manually. http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

There are also plugins like [duplicator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) which maybe useful to you.

Resources http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Why would you end up with broken links if you copied files? The link problem is a database problem, not a file problem. The files themselves are neutral. Unless the Core has been hacked it is no different than installing a new site from a fresh download.

Comment: You will when you copy the database over so i guess it could be worded differently however i did include the solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a site at `http://www.example.com/wordpress/` and you want to put one at `http://www.example.com/wordpress2/` then you should be able to just copy the `/wordpress/` directory and then edit your `wp-config.php` to use a different database prefix or a different database altogether.

But... I am not sure why you would do that. It is as at least as easy to upload a new, clean copy of WordPress via (s)FTP, and that route does not have the side effect of copying media from one site to another.

If you have a subdirectory install-- that is, files at `http://www.example.com/wordpress/` that display as if they were at `http://www.example.com/`-- then this is going to be more complicated. Hopefully, that isn't the case.

Comment: That's what I have :-) But it does not matter. One site can live at the root, the other at /whatever.

Comment: What is what you have?

Comment: The subdirectory installation I mean.